# Test already started: How to do big tests

Tags: unit-test, bulkification

I'd like to do a massive test.  We've got a fairly complex operation that runs on any of 160,000 records, all of which have various scenarios as children and could be crappy data in some cases.

I'd like to run a testmethod on EACH AND EVERY ONE OF THEM.

Any one of them generates a lot of queries--I tried grabbing 20 of them randomly and putting my test in a for loop and got the message "Testing started"

`test.startTest(); integer testoutput = class.method(var1, var2, var3);
            test.stopTest();`

Does that mean the tests in the for loop are executing in parallel?  Is there a way to sequentially go through all my records as a test?

Comment: So, test.startTest() is being called inside a for loop? You can only have one call to startTest per testMethod.

Comment: I apologize in advance for the long read. Please feel free to ask clarifying comments or update your question with more information. I'd also be willing to have a chat with you so we can have an interactive dialog about what the problem is and ways you can come to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Tests can run in parallel or serial mode (see the options panel in the Apex Test Execution screen). Each test will run once when queued. You can only use Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() once per test method, so you cannot loop through all possible records and test them. Also, batches may only run on up to 200 records, and only once per test method.

In other words, a test against 160,000 records is impractical, because you would need up to 160,000 tests-- even batching them together in sets of 200 would yield 800 different test methods, each of which would have to test the logic being tested. This is highly impractical from a coding standpoint (you would have to write 800-160,000 tests) as well as an execution standpoint (organizations are limited in the tests per day on a rolling 24 hour window).

You should instead break up your code into logical tests. Consider the scenario where you have TriggerA, TriggerB, and TriggerC, each on a different object. TriggerC can be invoked by saving a "C" record, while saving a "B" record invokes both TriggerB and TriggerC (it is recursive), and saving an "A" record will invoke TriggerA, TriggerB, and TriggerC, recursively.

A naive approach would be to throw every possible combination of data at TriggerA to try and test TriggerB and TriggerC, but this won't work because, practically speaking, TriggerA should have a finite number of outputs that are possible, and those outputs should either return an error (thus never calling TriggerB and TriggerC), or should be of a format that TriggerB can rely on as being "good" data, or at least can be reported back to TriggerA as "bad" data. Ideally, TriggerB should not care about if it is called directly or as a recursive function of TriggerA (there are obviously some exceptions to this guideline, of course).

The connecting data between TriggerA and TriggerB, and TriggerB and TriggerC are known as "contracts." Even though TriggerB and TriggerC must separately handle invalid data, TriggerA's "contract" with TriggerB is that it should never pass any data to TriggerB that it cannot handle correctly. Similarly, given ControllerA, ControllerB, and ControllerC, that are always invoked in order (say, in a page wizard), ControllerB should never receive data from ControllerA that it doesn't know how to handle. In fact, assuming ControllerB could never be called legitimately without first passing through ControllerA, it would be acceptable for ControllerB to only accept valid input-- ControllerB and ControllerA have a contract with each other; ControllerB agrees to accept data only from ControllerA, and ControllerA agrees to handle ControllerB only data it can handle.

In both cases, it would be better to visualize each unit as a flow chart, where that chart has a finite number of lines. Each logic unit should have a defined set of inputs and outputs, and reject any invalid input and strive to generate only defined output. It does not matter how complicated the entire process is, there should always be a finite number of connection points that exist between each logic unit.

By mechanical example, a car engine may have a thousand individual parts that operate as a whole. Surely this is more complex than a typical AppExchange program, and possibly even more complex than most desktop programs. Each part depends only on the parts that it is attached to. The physical connections ensure that each part performs only one specific task and has a set of inputs and outputs defined to that task. The alternator does not need to know how the radiator works, nor do the spark plugs care about the oil pan. In the same manner, you should be able to define discrete logical breaks where data passes from one logic unit to another-- each unit should be tested properly.

Some parts may need more testing than other parts, and that's okay. In our project that I've been working on, our largest logic units exceed 1000 lines of code, and it has to basically be tested as a whole. However, it interacts with many thousands of other lines of code that are not tested by that unit's tests, because they are not relevant directly to the function of this logic unit. I believe that unit has some odd 20 or 30 tests devoted to it to test various types of inputs and validate outputs.

The point of this answer is that if your process is so complicated that you cannot break it down into smaller parts, your code is in danger of being unmanageable, and you should focus on refactoring your code as soon as practical before it becomes impossible to maintain or add new features.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to test the validity of all the data in a database, you can't run a test method against them. That's not the purpose or point of testing. The testing system is designed to test unit logic.

However, if there's a concern that the data may be invalid, and you need an automated processor to test the data, you might write an Apex Code Batch class. Using this class, you can test the data of each and every record, and record the results in a logging object. If you do not want to commit any of the changes to the database, use `Database.setSavePoint()` and `Database.rollback()` during each iteration.

```
global class processData implements Database.Batchable<SOBject>, Database.Stateful {
    // store data here in a variable

    // Initialize query
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,Name FROM Account]);
    }

    // Process 200 records at once
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Account[] records) {
        System.SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
        // test each set of records

        // Discard all changes
        Database.rollback(sp);
    }

    // Finish up
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // Send an email or log interesting data, etc.
    }
}
```